# redirect wordpress site from non www to www using rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my site from non-www to www.Content of my htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^quadriacapital.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.quadriacapital.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But am getting error after putting this code into my htaccess "Page is not redirected properly".

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^quadriacapital.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.quadriacapital.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tried your code cleared the cache and refreshed it, still getting the same error "page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: am still getting error. Is there any other way to do it? I dont want to use any plugin.

Comment: it's redirecting to www but am getting too many redirects error again :(